# Specify Column types in read_csv by using values in a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to read in a directory of multiple csv files, each is about 7K+ rows and  ~ 1800 columns.  I have a data dictionary that I can read into a data frame, where each row of the data dictionary identifies the variable (column) name, as well as the data type.

In looking at `?read_csv` found within the `readr` package, it is possible to specify the column types.  However, given that I have nearly 1800 columns to specify, I was hoping to use the info from an available data dictionary to specify the column/type pairs in the proper format required by the function.

The alternative, which is less desirable, is to read in every column as a character and then modify as needed by hand.

Any help that you can provide on how to specify column types would be much appreciated.

If it helps, here is my code to get and coax the data dictionary into the format I am referring to.

```
## Get the data dictionary
URL = "https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx"
download.file(URL, destfile="raw-data/dictionary.xlsx")

## read in the dictionary to get the variables
dict = read_excel("raw-data/dictionary.xlsx", sheet = "data_dictionary")
colnames(dict) = tolower(gsub(" ", "_", colnames(dict)))
dict = dict %>% filter(!is.na(variable_name))

## create a data dictionary
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46738968/specify-column-types-in-read-csv-by-using-values-in-a-dataframe/46742411#46742411
dict <- dict %>% mutate(variable_type = case_when(api_data_type == "integer" ~ "i", 
                                                  api_data_type == "autocomplete" ~ "c", #assumption that this is a string
                                                  api_data_type == "string" ~ "c",
                                                  api_data_type == "float" ~ "d"))
```

returns :

```
> ## read in the dictionary to get the variables
> dict = read_excel("raw-data/dictionary.xlsx", sheet = "data_dictionary")
> colnames(dict) = tolower(gsub(" ", "_", colnames(dict)))
> dict = dict %>% filter(!is.na(variable_name))
> dict <- dict %>% mutate(variable_type = case_when(api_data_type == "integer" ~ "i", 
+                                                   api_data_type == "autocomplete" ~ "c", #assumption that this is a string
+                                                   api_data_type == "string" ~ "c",
+                                                   api_data_type == "float" ~ "d"))
Error: object 'api_data_type' not found
```

and my sessionInfo

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.2.0 readxl_0.1.1  readr_1.1.0   dplyr_0.5.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rjson_0.2.15   lazyeval_0.2.0 magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.2       assertthat_0.1 hms_0.2        DBI_0.7        tools_3.3.1   
 [9] tibble_1.2     yaml_2.1.14    Rcpp_0.12.11   stringi_1.1.5  jsonlite_1.5
```

Comment: I will post the "fully" reproducible solution shortly.

Comment: Maybe you have to upgrade your version of dplyr. I have v0.7.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `mutate` and `case_when` to map the `api_data_type` column using compact string representation. This is where each column type is represented by a single letter: c = character, i = integer, n = number, d = double, l = logical, etc. Now this character vector can be used in the `col_types` argument of `read_csv` .

```r
## Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

## Get the data dictionary
URL = "https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx"
download.file(URL, destfile="raw-data/dictionary.xlsx")

## read in the dictionary to get the variables
dict = read_excel("raw-data/dictionary.xlsx", sheet = "data_dictionary")
colnames(dict) = tolower(gsub(" ", "_", colnames(dict)))
dict = dict %>% filter(!is.na(variable_name))

unique(dict$api_data_type)
#> [1] "integer"      "autocomplete" "string"       "float"

dict <- dict %>% mutate(variable_type = case_when(api_data_type == "integer" ~ "i", 
                                                  api_data_type == "autocomplete" ~ "c", #assumption that this is a string
                                                  api_data_type == "string" ~ "c",
                                                  api_data_type == "float" ~ "d"
                                                  ) 
                        )  
cnames <- dict %>% select(variable_name) %>% pull
head(cnames)
#> [1] "UNITID" "OPEID"  "OPEID6" "INSTNM" "CITY"   "STABBR"
ctypes <- dict %>% select(variable_type) %>% pull
head(ctypes)
#> [1] "i" "i" "i" "c" "c" "c"
```

Comment: see the update above.  I wanted to expand upon the code I got when you gave me your suggestion.  See the error, but I wasn't aware of `case_when`, so +100 for that use-case

Comment: No problem, have another try of this fully reproducible example. Please remember to restart session prior to running the code.

Comment: I ran into an issue where the columns didnt match the data dictionary, but this was a great help.  Much appreciated